# using tag on a button and passing tag value in next view label-iphone

Tags: iphone

i am having some buttons whose tags have been set from 1 to 10.Now if user clicks on the buttons, the tag value should be send in next screen/nib's label.

```
-(IBAction) gotoGameScreen:(id)sender  
{  
    [self playAudio];    
UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;    
NSLog(@"Use Selected Level=%d",btn.tag);//here i am getting the tag value as 1.    
GameScreen *gameScreen = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameScreen" bundle:nil];    
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameScreen animated:YES];    
[gameScreen release];  
}
```

any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an integer in GameScreen and define property and synthesize it and pass value of present button tag to next ...

```
-(IBAction) gotoGameScreen:(id)sender
{

[self playAudio];

UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

NSLog(@"Use Selected Level=%d",btn.tag);

GameScreen *gameScreen = [[GameScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameScreen" bundle:nil];

gameScreen.tagValue=btn.tag;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameScreen animated:YES];

[gameScreen release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work. What you should do is to create an integer eg

```
int iButtonTag;
```

Set its property as

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) int iButtonTag;
```

and synthesize it.

Use this int to paas on the tag of button. This int containing button tag will be used in next viewController.